# Cannot get connection for redisTemplate for Spring data redis

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-redis

I'm trying to publish a message to a channel using Spring data Redis using Jedis. Here is a very simple Java config:

```
@Bean(name="jedisConnectionFactory")
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHostName(redisHostName);
    factory.setPort(redisPort);
    factory.setUsePool(true);
    return factory;
}

@Bean(name="redisTemplate")
RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<Object, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    return redisTemplate;
}
```

where redisPort=6379 and redisHostName="localhost".

When I run the following test:

```
 @Test
public void testRedis(){
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    RedisTemplate<Object,Object> redisTemplate = (RedisTemplate<Object, Object>) context.getBean("redisTemplate");
    redisTemplate.convertAndSend("test", "123");
}
```

I get the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:252)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:58)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:128)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:91)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:78)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:178)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:153)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.convertAndSend(RedisTemplate.java:676)
at com.jobvite.realtimeanalytics.redis.RedisTest.testRedis(RedisTest.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:443)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.<clinit>(JedisConnection.java:108)
... 44 more
```

Answer (score 18):

This issue is caused by the Jedis version (2.7.2) not compatible with Spring Data Redis (1.5.0.RELEASE). I used 3 days facing the same issue before I get inspired by this post and comment. Jedis version (2.6.2) is working fine (although I hit other errors in my program, but at least it have some progress than the same error message)!

Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped. I guess we need to pay attention to the POM to make sure the versions are compatible, since the stacktrace is usually not helpful when you run into these issues.

Comment: You saved my day @kwky. By the way, I am really confused, spring is suppressing exception in a really bad manner. They really do need to improve their code for JedisConnectionFactory.

Comment: Yeah. That is why I used such a long time to solve my issue. By the way, we can always beware with the compile depedencies listed in maven for certain jar. I think it is recommended to use the same version as listed there, to avoid similar issue happens again.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out I was using Jedis 2.7.2 but Spring Data Redis 1.5.0 seems to be compatible with Jedis 2.6.2. I wish this were a little clearer in the documentation somehow.

Comment: Same for spring data redis 1.4.4-RELEASE. There is a managed dependancy someware (I cannot find where from ... grrrrr) fetching Jedis 2.5.2

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I had this problem and have a solution.

Answer (score 4):

I have also faced a similar kind of issue. I did some research and found out that it is due to a jar conflict.

**Compatible version** i am using in my application is :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Or if you are using **spring boot** simply add the following dependency. Spring boot is smart enough to auto resolve such issues.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I hope it helps !!

Comment: Turns out spring boot is not always smart enough. Had the same issue with the spring-boot-starter-data-redis dependency. Was resolved by using separate spring-data-redis and jedis dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Compatible version：

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Version, I encountered the same problem,this spring-data-redis 1.5.0 pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
  <name>Spring Data Redis</name>
  <description>Spring Data Redis</description>
  <url>http://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis</url>
  <organization>
    <name>Pivotal Software, Inc.</name>
    <url>http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-redis</url>
  </organization>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <developers>
    <developer>
      <id>costin</id>
      <name>Costin Leau</name>
      <email>cleau@vmware.com</email>
      <properties>
        <twitter>costinl</twitter>
      </properties>
    </developer>
    <developer>
      <id>jencompgeek</id>
      <name>Jennifer Hickey</name>
      <properties>
        <twitter>jencompgeek</twitter>
      </properties>
    </developer>
    <developer>
      <id>christophstrobl</id>
      <name>Christoph Strobl</name>
      <properties>
        <twitter>stroblchristoph</twitter>
      </properties>
    </developer>
    <developer>
      <id>thomasdarimont</id>
      <name>Thomas Darimont</name>
      <properties>
        <twitter>thomasdarimont</twitter>
      </properties>
    </developer>
  </developers>
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis</developerConnection>
    <url>http://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis</url>
  </scm>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.8</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jredis</groupId>
      <artifactId>jredis-core-ri</artifactId>
      <version>06052013</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
      <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.spullara.redis</groupId>
      <artifactId>client</artifactId>
      <version>0.7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.10</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lambdaworks</groupId>
      <artifactId>lettuce</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jredis</groupId>
      <artifactId>jredis-core-api</artifactId>
      <version>06052013</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Navin Viswanath, thank you for the solution! How did you find it, using docs or debugging?

For those who use Gradle, here is my combination:

**Versions**:

- Redis 3.0.2
- Jedis 2.7.2
- Spring Data Redis 1.6.0 M1 (not available in maven central, because it's milestone release - add http://repo.spring.io/milestone/ repo)

**build.gradle**:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/release/' }
  maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone/' }
}

dependencies {
  compile group: 'redis.clients', name: 'jedis', version: '2.7.2'
  compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-redis', version: '1.6.0.M1'
}
```

Please note that Spring Data Redis `1.6.0.M1` will be removed once it becomes release, you need to change it to `1.6.0.RELEASE` when it is available as release.

So, I checked for version compatibility here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/gradle.properties and found related JIRA ticket here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-396

Answer (score 1):

had a similar problem with spring-boot-starter-data-redis 2.0.4

when i implicitly put the dependency to jedis in the app pom.xml it somehow worked

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

eclipse complains about "Duplicating managed version", but everything else works

Answer (score 1):

Compatible version:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Right. It is compatibility issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since July 2019, Spring Boot 2.X was compatible with Jedis 3.X (See [Upgrade to Jedis 3.1.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17622) for more info).
For those who use Gradle, an example is as follows:

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation 'redis.clients:jedis:3.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using Spring-boot-starter-data-redis

A permanent fix can be entered as follows:

1. Determine the version of spring-boot-starter-data-redis.  In
   eclipse, you can mouse over the dependency entry in your pom.xml
   file.  It will tell you the version you are using.
2. Navigate to that version directory in your maven repository.
3. Edit the pom file and add the version number of redis client that is needed.  In this case version 2.6.2.RELEASE to go with version
   1.50 of spring-boot-starter-data-redis.  In this case I had to add `<version>2.6.2.RELEASE</version`.
4. In your IDE, refresh your entire project. To do this in eclipse or STS, click once on the project name->right click select maven->Update     Project
5. Check your maven dependencies list and the jedis version should now be 2.6.2.
6. Compile your project.
7. Open the .war archive with jar or 7-zip etc.  Find the lib directory under WEB-INF and verify the presence of jedis-2.6.2.

That should resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can find spring data maven version compatible with jedis maven version from bellow link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-redis/1.5.9.RELEASE

[image]