# Spring cache with Redis: NullPointerException

Tags: spring, spring-cache

When I added `@Cacheable` annotation to my service method and executed it, I got following error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:252)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:58)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:128)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:153)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.get(RedisCache.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.get(RedisCache.java:90)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:68)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:461)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:432)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:333)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:299)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.findMember(Unknown Source)
    at com.fh.taolijie.test.dao.mapper.AccountServiceTest.testFind(AccountServiceTest.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:443)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.<clinit>(JedisConnection.java:108)
    ... 51 more
```

My configuration bean:

```
@Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, MemberModel> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, MemberModel> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(this.jedisConnectionFactory);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();

        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
        redisCacheManager.afterPropertiesSet();

        return redisCacheManager;
    }
```

Method that needs cache:

```
  @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Cacheable(value = "memberCache", key = "#username")
    public MemberModel findMember(String username, boolean isWired) {
        MemberModel mem = memMapper.selectByUsername(username);
        CheckUtils.nullCheck(mem);

        return mem;
    }
```

Everything looks like normal. I can't tell what's wrong here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be due to version compatibility between jedis and spring-data.

Saw this  - Spring Data Redis 1.5.0 seems to be compatible with Jedis 2.6.2

[Cannot get connection for redisTemplate for Spring data redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30447919/cannot-get-connection-for-redistemplate-for-spring-data-redis)