# Why Getting NoClassDefFound error for JedisConnection when using Spring Redis

Tags: java, spring, redis

Hello when trying to use spring-redis i am getting

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection
```

exception when doing any connection operation using redis. My config method goes like this

```
 @Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory jedisConnFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();

    jedisConnectionFactory.setHostName("XXX.XX.XX.XXX");

    jedisConnectionFactory.setPort(6381);
    jedisConnectionFactory.setUsePool(true);
    jedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jedisConnectionFactory;
```

Please suggest if anyone knows why i am getting this exception.

Comment: You are missing the library (or its not in your class path) that contains the class JedisConnection,.

Comment: You dont have it as a dependency, are you using maven?

Comment: If you are using Maven, then add these 2 guys : http://pastebin.com/i1yx6fqJ

Comment: You can find spring data maven version compatible with jedis maven version from bellow link:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-redis/1.5.9.RELEASE

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After wasting almost one day and finding that the jar is already on my class path, i further debugged it and found that when java's reflection mechanism was trying to find a method which was already present in the "methods list" it was not able to find due to some version conflict between **Jedis version (2.7.2) not compatible with Spring Data Redis (1.5.0.RELEASE)** , this issue has already been answered in this link ::
[Jedis and spring data redis version conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31023359/4136515)

Comment: How can we get this compatible information? Can you please mention it? documentation or other tools/ plugin?

Comment: I had to search now as this was 6 years ago when I faced the issue

Answer (score 19):

latest version that Redis client still keeps old package structure is: 2.10.2.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.2</version>
</dependency>
```

From 3.0.x, package structure has been changed. if spring-data-redis invokes Pool class of redis client with old package structure, then  **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**

seems latest **spring-data-redis: 2.1.10.RELEASE** still invokes Pool class of redis client with old package structure so you need to use redis.clients **2.10.2**

Answer (score 17):

JedisPoolConfig is needed when we use   Jedis Configuration. In Spring Boot 2.0, spring-boot-starter-data-redis gives Lettuce dependency by default instead of Jedis. To use Jedis configuration, exclude Lettuce and add Jedis as following.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>            
</dependency>        
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 12):

#### In my case I had to remove version tag

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly for me with Spring Boot 2.6.7 version. Thanks a lot!

Comment: yeah I have version 4.2.3, removing the version downgraded it to 3. something, now it works

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me too. I was using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.7.2 . And I was choosing 3.3.0 for jedis. which was wrong. Then I chose latest suggestion by maven and that also did not work. But I let maven choose correct version for jedis by removing version entry in xml . And it worked !!!!!! :))

Comment: Fwiw, this is relevant even if you're not using `spring-boot-starter`; even if you're just pulling in `spring-context`.

Answer (score 6):

latest version of Redis client solved my issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to compatible version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

JedisPoolConfig is needed when we use Jedis Configuration. In Spring Boot 2.0, spring-boot-starter-data-redis gives Lettuce dependency by default instead of Jedis. To use Jedis configuration, exclude Lettuce and add Jedis as following.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
     <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>           
</dependency>       
<dependency>
  <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
  <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The class `org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection` is not in your classpath. Please check if you have this dependency available and if it's missing include it.

The missing jar should be, given your redis version, like this from [Maven repository redis page](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-redis/1.0.0.RELEASE), so in the form `spring-data-redist-(your-version).jar`

Comment: Thanks for your input, The class is already present in my classpath , the issue is with the Jedis version (2.7.2) not compatible with Spring Data Redis version (1.5.0.RELEASE) as mentioned in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31023359/4136515). I am posting this link as an answer so that other people would find it useful.