# Redis Session with Java Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-session, spring-data-redis

I am trying to save my session instances withing the Redis server ruining on local host. When I start the application I am getting a error massage and application wont start. 
It looks like the class can not be found or bean is wrong but I do not understand the error message well.

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.739 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.kb.webkb.WebkbApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads(com.kb.webkb.WebkbApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.005 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisMessageListenerContainer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redisMessageListenerContainer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/kb/webkb/configuration/session/SessionConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/util/Pool
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/kb/webkb/configuration/session/SessionConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/util/Pool
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/util/Pool
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/util/Pool
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: redis.clients.util.Pool
```

It have used Jedis within the SessionConfiguration class to call for Jedis object.

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class SessionConfig extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {
    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }
}
```

I have tried a solution from this post: stackoverflow.com/q/33128318/11189140

but when I did I was/am getting this error

```
Description:

An attempt was made to call the method org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection.getConfig(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List; but it does not exist. Its class, org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/home/kbuczynski/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-redis/2.1.5.RELEASE/spring-data-redis-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisConnection.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/home/kbuczynski/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-redis/2.1.5.RELEASE/spring-data-redis-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar
```

POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.kb</groupId>
    <artifactId>webkb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>webkb</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: This seems to be already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/33128318/11189140

Comment: @AnirudhSimha I did found this solution and I did have tried it but i was given a different error. I edit my post so u can see the failure reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your error message there is an `NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/util/Pool` which resides in `redis/clients/jedis/util/Pool` since Jedis 3.

Please check your (managed) dependencies (`mvn dependency:tree`), if you are really still using Jedis in version 2.x.

At least [Spring Data Redis 2.1.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/2.1.x/pom.xml#L25) is using Jedis 2.9.3 where `redis/clients/util/Pool` is yet valid. Therefore I suspect conflicting dependencies in your case.

**Addendum**:

Thanks for sharing also your [project](https://github.com/NashPL/SpringStack). Now it's quite clear what is happening: The crucial part is your

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Please note that this is a **managed dependency** of Spring Boot, however you forced it to be in version `1.2.2.RELEASE`. Remove this one from your dependencies, `spring-session-data-redis` is doing everything you need for you.

I've committed this one and also an integration test in a my forked repo and created a [pull request](https://github.com/NashPL/SpringStack/pull/1) for you.

Please verify that it also works for you!

Comment: Looks like I am using 
[INFO] +- org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-redis:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile


Idea how to fix it if there is an issue ? I do not really understand how to fix it.

Comment: Your exact config and the dependencies in your `pom.xml` work here for me. When I ask `mvn dependency:tree` it show amongst other the following: `[INFO] +- redis.clients:jedis:jar:2.9.1:compile` – can you please verify this?

Comment: Hi I have created new project reusing the pom.xml file I have provided. I manage to get rid of annoying error however I am stuck with with

An attempt was made to call the method org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection.getConfig(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List; but it does not exist. Its class, org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection, is available from the following locations:

It suggest to fix the classpath so it contains a single, compatible version of spring reddis. Any suggestions how to do it ?

Comment: Could you possibly share your new project, maybe on Github?

Comment: Awesome I'll take look on it in a few hours and am confident for now. Because it's slightly after midnight here, first some hours of sleep. :-)

Comment: This answer helped me a lot! I the following reference helps too:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-jedis-instead-of-lettuce