# Spring java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring framework and following the tutorial on [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm). After including every thing, while running the program it gives me following error:

> Error: Unable to initialize main class com.raza.spring.MainApp
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext

Below is my project structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2X7R.png)

Here is the code:

Class Hello:

```
package com.raza.spring;
public class Hello {

    private String message;
    
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    
    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }
}
```

Class MainApp:

```
package com.raza.spring;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        Hello obj = (Hello) context.getBean("helloWorld");
        
        obj.getMessage();
    }

}
```

Beans.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id = "helloWorld" class = "com.raza.spring.Hello">
        <property name = "message" value = "Hello raza world !!!"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Not able to get what is wrong here. Thanks in advance.

I am trying tutorial on [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm) and expecting an output on the console.

Comment: How are you running it and specifying the classpath?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Getting NoClassDefFound error for JedisConnection when using Spring Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128318/why-getting-noclassdeffound-error-for-jedisconnection-when-using-spring-redis)

Comment: You should also look for newer tutorial.... This is probably around 2006 basing on Java 1.6 in setup.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext` tells that the Class you are using in your code is not accessible from your project.
In previous chapter on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_environment_setup.htm you probably downloaded spring library in step 4. Try adding it to your classpath: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project%27s_classpath%3F.

I highly recommend you start using maven. It allows you to add external libraries a lot easier, without having to manually download them from a git repo or a website.
Also, check the Baeldung courses. Their examples always use the latest Spring version https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tutorial