# Why Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: redis.clients.jedis.util.SafeEncoder exception when using spring-boot-starter-data-redis?

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I`m writing Camunda project, because of that I use **Spring Boot v2.7.9** and **Camunda Engine v7.19.0**. The project involves the use of several databases, one of them Redis, another databases is H2, PostgreSQL. To work with Redis I use **spring-boot-starter-data-redis** dependency, this is my Redis configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {
    @Value("${spring.data.redis.host}")
    private String redisHost;
    @Value("${spring.data.redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory factory =  new JedisConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHostName(redisHost);
        factory.setPort(redisPort);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

When I run application, this exception occurs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'getDSContactsDelegate' defined in file [C:\Users\ITleuov\IdeaProjects\credit-report\target\classes\kz\eubank\creditreport\delegate\GetDSContactsDelegate.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'partnerRepository' defined in kz.eubank.creditreport.repository.PartnerRepository defined in @EnableRedisRepositories declared on RedisRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableRedisRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisKeyValueTemplate' while setting bean property 'keyValueOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisKeyValueTemplate': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisKeyValueAdapter' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisKeyValueAdapter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisTemplate' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [kz/eubank/creditreport/config/RedisConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redisTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [kz/eubank/creditreport/config/RedisConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jedisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/util/SafeEncoder
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at kz.eubank.creditreport.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'partnerRepository' defined in kz.eubank.creditreport.repository.PartnerRepository defined in @EnableRedisRepositories declared on RedisRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableRedisRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisKeyValueTemplate' while setting bean property 'keyValueOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisKeyValueTemplate': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisKeyValueAdapter' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisKeyValueAdapter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisTemplate' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [kz/eubank/creditreport/config/RedisConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redisTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [kz/eubank/creditreport/config/RedisConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jedisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/util/SafeEncoder
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisKeyValueTemplate': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisKeyValueAdapter' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisKeyValueAdapter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisTemplate' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [kz/eubank/creditreport/config/RedisConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redisTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [kz/eubank/creditreport/config/RedisConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jedisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/util/SafeEncoder
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:693) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:198) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisKeyValueAdapter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisTemplate' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [kz/eubank/creditreport/config/RedisConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redisTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [kz/eubank/creditreport/config/RedisConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jedisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/util/SafeEncoder
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:693) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:198) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [kz/eubank/creditreport/config/RedisConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redisTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [kz/eubank/creditreport/config/RedisConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jedisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/util/SafeEncoder
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [kz/eubank/creditreport/config/RedisConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jedisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/util/SafeEncoder
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jedisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/util/SafeEncoder
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    ... 86 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/util/SafeEncoder
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConverters.toBytes(JedisConverters.java:232) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConverters.<clinit>(JedisConverters.java:109) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.<clinit>(JedisConnectionFactory.java:93) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at kz.eubank.creditreport.config.RedisConfig.jedisConnectionFactory(RedisConfig.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at kz.eubank.creditreport.config.RedisConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5f62064.CGLIB$jedisConnectionFactory$1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at kz.eubank.creditreport.config.RedisConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5f62064$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a785d9a9.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at kz.eubank.creditreport.config.RedisConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5f62064.jedisConnectionFactory(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    ... 87 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: redis.clients.jedis.util.SafeEncoder
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 101 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I tried to search solution for this error, a lot of solutions was about version conflict, but there used **jedis **and **spring-data-redis** dependencies not **spring-boot-starter-data-redis**, so I can't find solution for this. Can you tell me what problem I admit?

Comment: Did you try the solutions for jedis and spring-data-redis? What were the results?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are creating your own `JedisConnectionFactory` bean from the  `spring.data.redis.*` properties instead of letting Spring Boot auto-configuration create that bean for you?

Comment: Please share your Maven `pom.xml` or Gradle `build.gradle` file to show the combination of dependencies you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the Jedis dependency. In your POM for Spring Boot 2.7.9 you'll need:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
  <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Except the `version` should be removed from the `redis.clients:jedis` dependency so that the version managed by Spring Boot is used automatically. This will prevent problems with future upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

Which spring-boot-starter-data-redis version are you using? It certainly depends on spring-data-redis, so related fixes apply.

This boils down to "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/util/SafeEncoder".

For instance [Why Getting NoClassDefFound error for JedisConnection when using Spring Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128318/why-getting-noclassdeffound-error-for-jedisconnection-when-using-spring-redis)
describes the issue.
The solution here is:

> From 3.0.x, package structure has been changed. if spring-data-redis
> invokes Pool class of redis client with old package structure, then
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError seems latest spring-data-redis:
> 2.1.10.RELEASE still invokes Pool class of redis client with old package structure so you need to use redis.clients 2.10.2

Try upgrading to Spring Boot Starter Data Redis to 3.0.6
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-redis

Comment: spring-boot-starter-data-redis version 2.7.9

Comment: Well, why don't you try a new one, like 3.0.6. 2.x seems to be the old package structure and 3.x new

Comment: You should not upgrade a dependency like `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` to a version that is different from the Spring Boot version. That is, don't mix Spring Boot 2.7.9 with Spring Boot Starter Data Redis 3.0.6. They will not be compatible.

Comment: Obviously starter and spring boot should be compatible versions

Comment: I can`t use spring boot version 3 and upper. because Camunda work with 2.7.9 and lower